# Why are requests made for RxJs typescript files only when my site is hosted by IIS?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, iis-8

When I build/run my site under Visual Studio / IIS Express, my site runs fine, no unusual requests, 404s, etc.

However when I publish my site to IIS and try to run it I'm greeted with a bunch of requests for typescript files (.ts), mostly related to RxJs.

For example, requests are made for:

http://www.example.com/lib/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts

http://www.example.com/lib/rxjs/src/Subject.ts

http://www.example.com/lib/rxjs/src/Observable.ts

http://www.example.com/lib/rxjs/src/util/toSubscriber.ts

... and many more

Why does this happen? 
The lib folder on my IIS site is an exact copy of the lib folder used by IIS Express.
One thing I will note is that my typings folder, tsconfig.json, and typings.json are not published.  Should they be?

Package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "0.6.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.11",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.17",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.22.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "typings": "^1.3.3",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.0"
  }
```

systemjs.config.js:

```
    /**
     * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
     * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
     */
    (function (global) {

        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        var map = {
            'app': 'app', // 'dist',
            '@angular': 'lib/@angular',
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'lib/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
            'rxjs': 'lib/rxjs'
        };

        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        var packages = {
            'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
            'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
        };

        var ngPackageNames = [
          'common',
          'compiler',
          'core',
          'forms',
          'http',
          'platform-browser',
          'platform-browser-dynamic',
          'router',
          'upgrade'
        ];

        // Individual files (~300 requests):
        function packIndex(pkgName) {
            packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
        }

        // Bundled (~40 requests):
        function packUmd(pkgName) {
            packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
        }

        // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
        var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;

        //setPackageConfig = packIndex;

        // Add package entries for angular packages
        ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);

        var config = {
            map: map,
            packages: packages
        };

        System.config(config);

    })(this);
```

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <base href="/">
        <title>Sams Blog - Debug</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
        <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
        <script src="lib/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
        <script src="js/site.js"></script>
        <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!--<script src="css/bootstrap/js/carousel.js"></script>-->
        <script src="lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
        <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
        <script>
            System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <my-app>Loading App...</my-app>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Bundle your scripts with rollupjs before publishing, so you will have only one request, and can get rid of systemjs. Use systemjs for development only.

Comment: Thank you - I actually use webpack and I have a similar problem... except webpack causes an error with zone.js.  I posted the problem with systemjs just because the individual requests are easier to troubleshoot (I think), hopefully I will get to the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this time it wasn't my bad.  I moved to angular rc7 and moved up a release in a few other packages and works now.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "0.6.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.17",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.22.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.4",
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "typings": "^1.3.3",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.0"
  }
```